# MVC 2 TextBoxFor doesn't work outside view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I wanted to remove repeated code from my 'edit' view forms by writing a method to generate the HTML for the field name, input box, and any validation messages.  Here is an example of the default view code generated by the system:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.dateAdded) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dateAdded, String.Format("{0:g}", Model.dateAdded)) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dateAdded) %>
</div>
```

And here is what I started to write:

```
MvcHtmlString DataField(HtmlHelper h, Object m)
{
    string s=h.TextBoxFor(m => m.dateAdded);
}
```

Now I know that won't work properly, it's just a start, but I get the error "'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'TextBoxFor' and no extension method 'TextBoxFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to write a custom HTML helper that would generate this HTML? I would recommend you using a custom editor template because what you have is primary markup. So you could have the following partial (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SomeViewModel.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Models.SomeViewModel>" %>
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.dateAdded) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dateAdded, String.Format("{0:g}", Model.dateAdded)) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dateAdded) %>
</div>
```

and then whenever you have a strongly typed view to SomeViewModel simply:

```
<%= Html.EditorForModel() %>
```

or if you have a property of type SomeViewModel:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomePropertyOfTypeSomeViewModel) %>
```

which would render the custom editor template.

As far as the helper is concerned the proper signature would be:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DataField(this HtmlHelper<SomeViewModel> htmlHelper)
    {
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(x => x.dateAdded);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try doing it the way you said.  I don't really know what I'm doing so it's likely I was doing it completely wrong.

Comment: How can I make it generic so it'll work for all models and fields?  At the moment 'dateAdded' is hardcoded and so is the model name.  Looks like I'll need to pass in formatting info as well.

Comment: @Dan, you could declare it like this: `public static MvcHtmlString DataField<TModel, TResult>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)`